# WebView component from Microsoft doesn't show local pages

Tags: c#, .net, webview

I am using a WebView component (Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView) and if I use the following code, I could see external web pages, but not local web pages (files are stored at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebs\Home and hosted on IIS). It makes no difference if the local page is .asp or .htm. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and .Net framework 4.7.2

```
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url1 = "https://www.google.com";
        string url2 = "http://localhost/MyWebs/Home/default.asp";
        webView1.Navigate(new Uri(url1)); // displays google page
        // webView1.Navigate(new Uri(url2)); // displays blank page but if I enter the address in a browser, it works fine
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use direct ip instead of localhost?

Comment: I tried it now, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: how about firewall try to run `netsh firewall add allowedprogram C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe MyApp ENABLE`, and check IIS settings

Comment: Good idea. I disabled the firewall and still not working. I added my projects folder to the list of exceptions of the antivirus long time ago.

Comment: Is this mobile app?Also you can make your IIS website public)

Comment: Both the IIS and the application are running on Windows 10 Pro desktop. I can access the IIS pages from any browser. Besides, instead of using WebView, I made another application where I used Chromium Web Browser (CefSharp) instead and that one can access the page fine.